# How to fetch the Makes name of the given Brand of Type=Car? [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5

I have following tables in Laravel.

### brands

```
id  name
1   honda
2   suzuki
```

### types

```
id  name
1   cars
2   bikes
```

### makes

```
id name               type_id
1  honda amaze        1
2  honda shine        2
3  suzuki baleno      1
4  suzuki racing      2
```

### brand_make

```
id  brand_id   make_id
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    2         3
4    2         4
```

### brand_type

```
id  brand_id   type_id
1    1         1
2    1         2
3    2         1
4    2         2
```

From the above tables, now how can I fetch all the Makes of Brand which has `type_id = 1`? E.g. Give me all Make of Honda cars

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Do you already have your models set up for the tables?

Comment: Yes. There are models.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('make')->select('makes.name as makes_name')->
leftjoin('type as t','make.type_id','=','type.id')->where('t.id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: Describe your answer as well. Don't only paste your code

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('brands')->join('brand_makes')->on('brands.id', '=, 'brand_makes.brand_id')
->join('makes')->on('makes.id', '=', 'brand_makes.make_id')
->join('types')->on('types.id', '=', 'makes.type_id)
->select('makes.name')
->where('types.name', 'cars')
->where('brands.name', 'yourRequiredBrand')
->get()
```

Comment: It would be more better if you use the eloquent rather than this raw query.
Maintain the relationships on each models and work accordingly.